# Topic views do not show up in jTable

Tags: sql, swing, ms-access

I try to code a forum using java swing. Firstly, on click for the jTable, it will lead to eForumContent.class which pass in the id together.

```
    jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                int id = 0;
                eForumTopics topics = new eForumTopics(id);
                topics.retrieveDiscussion();
                eForumThreadContent myWindow = new eForumThreadContent(id);
                myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

I initialize the id first. But I set my id in database table to auto number. Then I call the retrieveDiscussion method to get the id from database and pass it to eForumThreadContent. Here are my codes for retrieveDiscussion method.

```
        public boolean retrieveDiscussion(){
    boolean success = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM forumTopics WHERE topic_id = '" + id
            + "'";
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
    }
```

Then, inside the eForumThreadContent, I want to display the content of chosen thread using a table. So I use the id which I pass in just now and insert into my sql statement. Here are my codes.

```
        public eForumThreadContent(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    if (jTable == null) {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector(); // Vector class allows dynamic
                                            // array of objects
        Vector data = new Vector();
        try {
            DBController db = new DBController();
            db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
            String dsn = "IT Innovation Project";
            String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
            String sql = "Select topic_title,topic_description,topic_by from forumTopics WHERE topic_id = '"+id+"'";
            java.sql.Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
                }
                data.addElement(row);
            }
            resultSet.close();
            ((Connection) statement).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        jTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if (i == 1) {
                column.setPreferredWidth(400); // second column is bigger
            }else {
                column.setPreferredWidth(200);
            }
        }
        String header[] = { "Title", "Description", "Posted by" };

        for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column1 = jTable.getTableHeader().getColumnModel()
                    .getColumn(i);

            column1.setHeaderValue(header[i]);
        }
        jTable.getTableHeader().setFont( new Font( "Dialog" , Font.PLAIN, 20 ));
        jTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
        jTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        jTable.setEnabled(false);
        jTable.setRowHeight(100);
        jTable.getRowHeight();
        jTable.setFont( new Font( "Dialog" , Font.PLAIN, 18 ));
    }
    return jTable;
}
```

However, the table inside eForumThreadContent is empty even when I clicked on certain thread. It also gives me an error message.

```
    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at DBController.database.DBController.readRequest(DBController.java:27)
at kioskeForum.entity.eForumTopics.retrieveDiscussion(eForumTopics.java:67)
at kioskeForum.ui.eForumDiscussion$3.mouseClicked(eForumDiscussion.java:296)
```

I research online to get an idea for topic views using id. But my table does not show up anything. Can somebody enlighten me how to fix it? Or any other ways to display topic views in java swing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's still the same. Same error message. I roughly knew what's wrong with my code. I think is the part which I initialize the id to 0 so the id will become 0 all the way. But how can I get the id based on the rows in table accordingly? use a for loop?

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? I am seriously lost.

Comment: Ya I removed already but the error is still there. Does auto number in ms access equals to int in java?

Comment: Now I thinking how can the program know this id belongs to this row inside the table since I have many categories. And even I changed the id number, there's still nothing appear in my table.

Comment: I am still stuck. Can somebody enlighten me? Now my table have something to appear already. But it is fix with the id which I set to it. It is not dynamic yet. Any way to display it in dynamic way?

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Can somebody enlighten me? I know cannot use the row count to get the id number because I have many categories. For example, row one id one is for this category but for other category, it might be row one but id is different. Is there any other ways? I cannot search anything thru online.